# How to inspect if a GENERIC lambda is callable with a certain input arguement type?

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

Is there anyway to check if a generic lambda is callable with a specific type?!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A { void DoAStuff() {} };
struct B { void DoBStuff() {} };

int main() {
    auto fn = [](auto& arg) { arg.DoAStuff(); };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_invocable<decltype(fn), A&>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_invocable<decltype(fn), B&>::value << std::endl;
}
```

this code doesn't compile and I understand why. but I am wondering if there is anyway to get something like this to work? like we can define a class than when passed the lambda, return false instead of compilation error

> error: no member named 'DoAStuff' in 'B'

Comment: "*this code doesn't compile*" What compile error do you get? Besides the fact that `is_invocable` is not part of C++14...

Comment: @NicolBolas updated the question, I have my version of is_ivocable in c++14.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do when you use `B`?

Comment: I am hoping for answer to get FALSE, so I can use it in a SFINAE type concept.

Comment: This is not possible. The error comes from inside the definition of the lambda. SFINAE will only work on the function signature. You'll need to explicitly SFINAE on the availability of `doAStuff`.

Comment: Adding a trailing return type will make it work, not an answer to OP's question though. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186621