# Why doesn't std::is_invocable work with templated operator() which return type is auto-deduced (eg. generic lambdas)

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, return-type-deduction

c++17 introduces [`template <class Fn, class...ArgTypes> struct is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable):

> Determines whether `Fn` can be invoked with the arguments `ArgTypes...`. Formally, determines whether `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed when treated as an unevaluated operand, where `INVOKE` is the operation defined in `Callable`.

However, this template does not work with *templated operator()* which (direct or indirect) return type is auto-deduced:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int a() { return 1; }
};

struct B {};

struct {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(T t) { return t.a(); }
} f1;

struct {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(T t) -> decltype(t.a()) { return t.a(); }
} f2;

struct {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(T t) -> decltype(f1(t)) { return f1(t); }
} f3;

template<typename F, typename T>
void check(F&& f, T) {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_invocable_v<F, T> << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  check(f1, A());   // true
  check(f2, A());   // true
  check(f3, A());   // true
  //check(f1, B()); // error: ‘struct B’ has no member named ‘a’
  check(f2, B());   // false
  //check(f3, B()); // error: ‘struct B’ has no member named ‘a’
  return 0;
}
```

I guess the reason may be related to SFINAE. But this is still not intuitive. I tried to check [N4659 draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/master/papers)'s paragraphs which introduced `std::is_invocable`, but still couldn't find more detail about this behaivor. Since I am not an expert in this area, there may be omissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I guess the reason may be related to SFINAE.

Indeed. We call things like `f1` "SFINAE-unfriendly":

```cpp
struct {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(T t) { return t.a(); }
} f1;
```

That's because `f1` advertises itself as being invocable with *anything* (there are no constraints at all) but to find out what the call operator actually returns, you have to instantiate the body of the call operator. That involves determining the type of the expression `t.a()`, but at this point we're outside of the "immediate context" of the instantiation. Any failure at this point is not a substitution failure - it's a hard compile error.

`f2` on the other hand:

```cpp
struct {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(T t) -> decltype(t.a()) { return t.a(); }
} f2;
```

is SFINAE-friendly. The check for `t.a()` happens in the immediate context of the substitution, so an error in that expression leads to the function simply being removed from the candidate set. `is_invocable` can check this and determine `false`.

`f3` is the same as `f1` - while we check `f1(t))` in the immediate context, the actual resolution of `decltype(f1(t))` is still outside the immediate context, so it's still a hard compiler error.

---

The short version is: no type traits or concepts work unless you're SFINAE-friendly. Any failures must be in the immediate context.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.I found that some traits (such as `std::invoke_result`) have this description: `Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to Fn and ArgTypes. Only the validity of the immediate context of the
expression is considered. The compilation of the expression
can result in side effects such as the instantiation of class template
specializations and function template specializations, the generation
of implicitly-defined functions, and so on. Such side effects are not in
the “immediate context” and can result in the program being
ill-formed.`

Comment: ... But `std::is_invocable` has no such description. Is this requirement("any failures must be in the immediate context.") applied by default(implictly) to all standard traits that may be implemented by SFINAE ?

Comment: @VainMan Yeah I'm not sure that text appears for some traits but not all traits. That seems like an omission.