# Why is const member function template is instantiated for non-const object?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

I've stumbled upon an issue where const member function template is instantiated for non-const object which results in a compilation error.
Here's the reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
    using Data = int;

    Data data{};

    template <typename F> requires std::is_invocable_v<F, Data&>
    void func(F)
    {
        puts("S::func(F)");
    }

    template <typename F> requires std::is_invocable_v<F, const Data&>
    void func(F) const
    {
        puts("S::func(F) const");
    }
};

struct FuncObj {
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(T&)
    {
        // imaginary code that uses T assuming that it's non-const
        static_assert(!std::is_const_v<T>);
    }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.func(FuncObj());
}
```

When compiling this code I get "static assertion failed" error.
Now, I do know that this error is caused by return type of `FuncObj::operator()` being `auto` and needing
to be deduced, thus requiring instantiation of template function body, I learned this from this question:
[Why doesn't std::is_invocable with with templated operator() which return type is auto-deduced (e.g. generic lambdas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186621/why-doesnt-stdis-invocable-work-with-templated-operator-which-return-type-i).

I do understand that part. But what I don't understand is why does compiler even consider const member function (`S::func(F) const`) when
`S s` is not a const object?
There would be no error if compiler just deduced/instantiated `S::func(F)` (non-const member function).
Also, if instead of `requires` (or SFINAE) on `void func(F) const` I use `static_assert` with same condition *inside* the function,
the error goes away:

```cpp
    template <typename F> 
    void func(F) const // requires std::is_invocable_v<F, const Data&>
    {
        static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<F, const Data&>);
        puts("S::func(F) const");
    }
```

This seems very unintuitive, I cannot think of any reason as to why would compiler try `const` version of the member function when there's a non-const one?
Are there any places in the C++ standard where it is explained so that I can understand this?

Comment: `std::is_invocable_v` needs `operator()` to do overload resolution. How else will it give an answer? Since this means `operator()` must be instantiated... you know the rest.

Comment: Here's the entirely minimal example demonstrating it: https://godbolt.org/z/xYba4hqs5 - `auto` return type deduction is simply not sfinae friendly.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I wrote in my question that I know about that and even linked question, I'm asking why does compiler consider const-member function on a non-const object?

Comment: my question has nothing to do with sfinae, it's about why compiler even considers const overload of the member function for a non-const object, when there is a non-const member function

Comment: Because you can call const functions on non-const objects. That makes it a viable candidate for overload resolution, and so it will be checked in overload resolution. The fact there's a tie breaker won't skip the check, because it's the check that considers the tie breaker in the first place.

Comment: Using a static assert in the function body doesn't trigger it because the body **is not instantiated** if the overload isn't called. Constraints *are* instantiated for overload resolution.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica okay, now I get the idea, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have correctly understood that both overloads of `func` are candidates for the member function call `s.func(FuncObj());`.

The compiler has to check whether `std::is_invocable_v<F, const Data&>` is true for the second overload, which involves checking whether `F(D)` is well-formed, where `D` is of type `const Data&`. `D` being `const Data&` does not prevent a `T&` from binding to it. It would simply mean that `T` deduces to `const Data`. Nothing has been knocked out of the overload set yet.

Because `F` is `FuncObj`, and `FuncObj::operator()` has deduced return type, it is necessary to instantiate it.
During instantiation:

```cpp
template <typename T> // T  = const Data
auto operator()(T&)   // T& = const Data&
{
    // std::is_const_v<const Data> is true, so this static assertion fails.
    // The program is ill-formed because a static_assertion has failed.
    static_assert(!std::is_const_v<T>);
}
```

The compiler actually tells you precisely where this error is taking place:

```
<source>:27:23: error: static assertion failed due to requirement '!std::is_const_v<const int>'
   27 |         static_assert(!std::is_const_v<T>);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  [...]

<source>:15:36: note: while substituting template arguments into constraint expression here
   15 |     template <typename F> requires std::is_invocable_v<F, const Data&>
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:34:7: note: while checking constraint satisfaction for template 'func<FuncObj>' required here
   34 |     s.func(FuncObj());
      |       ^~~~
```

In general, `static_assert` is not SFINAE-friendly, and any assertion failures in function bodies are going to make the program ill-formed instead of knocking a candidate out of an overload set.
It's called "*Substitution* failure is not an error", not "*Instantiation* failure is not an error".

As you've pointed out, you could have written:

```cpp
template <typename T> requires (!std::is_const_v<T>)
```

This would have compiled with no error. It would have also been fine if you had used `void` instead of a deduced return type, because checking for expression validity would not involve instantiation the function template.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it. The problem is that my code works with user-provided callbacks, which are usually lambdas, so it by default has `auto` return type, and I don't want to document all this behavior in my code and force user to use constraints or `-> void`, so I'll stick with removing `requires` from const member function and making it a `static_assert` inside const member function body.

Comment: @felps321 checking whether something is `const` is a code smell anyway. What you really want is to check whether a type is assignable, for instance. Even if it's not `const`, it could still be effectively immutable, so very little is gained by checking it. I don't think it's unreasonable to document that the user's callbacks need to be properly constrained. If the user provides a lambda `[](Data&) {}`, (not using `auto`), then it can't be called with a `const Data&`. Using non-generic lambdas can help here.

Comment: yeah it's a code smell but the problem is that in my real code there is no const checks or static assertions, user callback just instantiated some template with `T` from generic lambda and this instantiation failed with multi-thousand line error message.

Comment: all because user code assumed that T is non-const and rightfully so because function that takes a callback was called on a non-const object. For example imagine you implement some value container type and you provide a function to access this value through a callback. Now imagine that callback wants to move the value, it will fail for `std::unique_ptr` because when `T`  is `const std::unique_ptr&` `std::move`d value will be const. All because this value container class has const overload.