# constrained member function preferes const overload over non-const

Tags: c++, c++20

I wonder why the following code preferes the `const` overload of the constraint member function, when the non-`const` version is also applicable.
I would really like to constraint the param as shown and it does compile when I'm explicit, but using `auto&` as param should also be possible. Has anyone an idea how to solve that?

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    template <std::invocable<const std::string&> Func>
    decltype(auto) Apply(Func func) const
    {
        return std::invoke(func, m_Inner);
    }

    template <std::invocable<std::string&> Func>
    decltype(auto) Apply(Func func)
    {
        return std::invoke(func, m_Inner);
    }

private:
    std::string m_Inner;
};

int main()
{
    Foo sync{};

    // works
    sync.Apply(
        [](std::string& s) { s = "Hello, World!"; });

    // does not work, because const overload is preferred
    sync.Apply(
        [](auto& s) { s = "Hello, World!"; });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Why do you think the const overload is preferred?

Comment: What is a "constraint member function"?

Comment: @Barry Well, because it doesn't compile... and I digged through the compile errors, which says, the ``std::string`` is const.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it makes `auto& s` into a `const std::string&` instead of complaining about ambiguity.

Comment: (The `auto` return of the lambda has to be deduced, so the function body is instantiated for `auto = const std::string&` when checking if the constraint for the const overload is satisfied, even if it eventually won't be used (the compiler doesn't know that yet). The fix is `[](auto& s) -> void { s = "Hello, world!"; }`

Comment: @Artyer That works, but I didn't understand the explanation. Would you mind fleshing it out in an answer?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a condensed explanation because this is the same question as the dupe. The answer in the duped question https://stackoverflow.com/a/76994569/5754656 and also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64187214/5754656 give good explanations.

Comment: The interesting part is, when I make the constraints of both overloads equal, then everything works. So, in certain circumstances the ``const`` is indeed the tie-breaker, but in other not. https://godbolt.org/z/b9xd4TP8o

Comment: @Artyer Thanks! I've started to look at it to try to come up with a concept that _could_ work in this situation. Interesting. Never stumbled across it myself.

Comment: Oh, I think I see where I was mistaken. Thanks.